# Python/Pandas convert string to time only

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas dataframe in Python 2.7.

```
import pandas as pd
trial_num = [1,2,3,4,5]
sail_rem_time = ['11:33:11','16:29:05','09:37:56','21:43:31','17:42:06']
dfc = pd.DataFrame(zip(*[trial_num,sail_rem_time]),columns=['Temp_Reading','Time_of_Sail'])
print dfc
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
  Temp_Reading Time_of_Sail
             1     11:33:11
             2     16:29:05
             3     09:37:56
             4     21:43:31
             5     17:42:06
```

This dataframe comes from a *.csv file. I use Pandas to read in the *.csv file as a Pandas dataframe. When I use `print dfc.dtypes`, it shows me that the column `Time_of_Sail` has a datatype `object`. I would like to convert this column to `datetime` datatype BUT I only want the time part - I don't want the year, month, date.

I can try this:

```
dfc['Time_of_Sail'] = pd.to_datetime(dfc['Time_of_Sail'])
dfc['Time_of_Sail'] = [time.time() for time in dfc['Time_of_Sail']]
```

but the problem is that the when I run `print dfc.dtypes` it still shows that the column `Time_of_Sail` is `object`.

Is there a way to convert this column into a datetime format that only has the time?

**Additional Information:**

To create the above dataframe and output, this also works:

```
import pandas as pd
trial_num = [1,2,3,4,5]
sail_rem_time = ['11:33:11','16:29:05','09:37:56','21:43:31','17:42:06']
data = [
    [trial_num[0],sail_rem_time[0]],
    [trial_num[1],sail_rem_time[1]],[trial_num[2],sail_rem_time[2]],
    [trial_num[3],sail_rem_time[3]]
    ]
dfc = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Temp_Reading','Time_of_Sail'])
dfc['Time_of_Sail'] = pd.to_datetime(dfc['Time_of_Sail'])
dfc['Time_of_Sail'] = [time.time() for time in dfc['Time_of_Sail']]
print dfc
print dfc.dtypes
```

Comment: I'm using python 3.4 but am having trouble reproducing your problem. When I tried the conversions you suggested, I find the dtype has changed to `datetime64[ns]`. As a side note, the construction of your dataframe didn't work for me because zip returns an iterator which is not accepted by the DataFrame constructor. This is probably a very stupid question, but have you tried running the exact code you posted?

Comment: Yeah, just tried it again. Works good for me. After I tried both the conversions, the `dtype` is `object`, though the `dtype` changes to `datetime64[ns]` if only the first conversion is run.

Comment: You're saying it's working now?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Okay, I added another way to create the dataframe and the problem. That might be helpful - this new way seems a bit more straightforward to me.

Comment: This is because pandas doesn't have a data type for time alone as far as I'm aware. The object type in pandas maps to a python base type of string. What is it you're trying to accomplish? As a side note, rather than creating the list in your edited example explicitly, you can pass the iterator that `zip()` returns to `list()` as `list(zip([trial_num,sail_rem_time]))`. That will return a list as `DataFrame()` expects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114572/discussion-between-hobenkr-and-w-r).

Comment: Let me think about this some more. i may be able to add some more details to the OP before taking this further. I'll think a bit about the requirements here.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

These two lines:

```
dfc['Time_of_Sail'] = pd.to_datetime(dfc['Time_of_Sail'])
dfc['Time_of_Sail'] = [time.time() for time in dfc['Time_of_Sail']]
```

Can be written as:

```
dfc['Time_of_Sail'] = pd.to_datetime(dfc['Time_of_Sail'],format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.time
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem - I could specify the format for the time (no date), which I was after,

Comment: Can you please tell what is `dt.time` at end and what does it do. I'm guessing it is imported datetime module

Comment: Is it possible to do this `inplace`?

Comment: Hi this will cause the dtype to be object and not datime.

Comment: @Nikko But afterwards if u do an invalid operation like dfc[dfc['Time_of_Sail']>'17:00:00'] you get an errorTypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str' so I guess it is datetime even though pandas just says object. Strange though because again then doing something like `dfc['Time_of_Sail'].dt.strftime('%H%M')` gives an error `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Answer (score 14):

Using to_timedelta,we can convert string to time format(timedelta64[ns]) by specifying units as second,min etc.,

```
dfc['Time_of_Sail'] = pd.to_timedelta(dfc['Time_of_Sail'], unit='s')
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

`dfc['Time_of_Sail'] = pd.to_datetime(dfc['Time_of_Sail'], format='%H:%M:%S' ).apply(pd.Timestamp)`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is searching for a more generalized answer try

```
dfc['Time_of_Sail']= pd.to_datetime(dfc['Time_of_Sail'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a simple conversion you can do the below:

```
import datetime as dt

dfc.Time_of_Sail = dfc.Time_of_Sail.astype(dt.datetime)
```

or you could add a holder string to your time column as below, and then convert afterwards using an apply function:

```
dfc.Time_of_Sail = dfc.Time_of_Sail.apply(lambda x: '2016-01-01 ' + str(x))
dfc.Time_of_Sail = pd.to_datetime(dfc.Time_of_Sail).apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.time(x))
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Not sure if it's just an older version in the answer but I do: `df["Time"].astype(datetime.datetime)` I get: `TypeError: dtype '<class 'datetime.datetime'>' not understood`

Answer (score 0):

(Tested with Python 3.10.9/pandas 1.5.3)
You can apply `pd.to_datetime()` and `datetime.time` to *the Series* with the `apply()` function and the `dt` accessor: `dfc['Time_of_Sail'].apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.time`.

**Recap**

```
import pandas as pd

# Original DataFrame
>>> dfc = pd.DataFrame(
>>>     {
>>>         'Temp_Reading': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
>>>         'Time_of_Sail': ['11:33:11', '16:29:05', '09:37:56', '21:43:31', '17:42:06']
>>>     }
>>> )

# Convert to datetime.time object
>>> dfc['Time_of_Sail'] = dfc['Time_of_Sail'].apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.time
>>> dfc['Time_of_Sail']
    0    11:33:11
    1    16:29:05
    2    09:37:56
    3    21:43:31
    4    17:42:06
    Name: Time_of_Sail, dtype: object
```

**Data type**
Indeed `dfc.dtypes` returns `Time_of_Sail  object`, but you'll see they are `datetime.time` objects at a closer look:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([i for i in dfc['Time_of_Sail']])
[datetime.time(11, 33, 11),
 datetime.time(16, 29, 5),
 datetime.time(9, 37, 56),
 datetime.time(21, 43, 31),
 datetime.time(17, 42, 6)]
```