# Convert Python object column in dataframe to time without date using Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib, time

I have a column in my dataframe that lists time in `HH:MM:SS`. When I run dtype on the column, it comes up with `dtype('o')` and I want to be able to use it as the `x-axis` for plotting some of my other signals. I saw previous documentation on using `to_datetime` and tried to use that to convert it to a usable time format for `matplotlib`.

Used pandas version is 0.18.1

I used:

```
time=pd.to_datetime(df.Time,format='%H:%M:%S')
```

where the output then becomes:

```
time
0       1900-01-01 00:00:01
```

and is carried out for the rest of the data points in the column.

Even though I specified just hour,minutes,and seconds I am still getting date. Why is that? I also tried

```
time.hour()
```

just to extract the hour portion but then I get an error that it doesn't have an 'hour' attribute.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!
[image: Sample data in image]

Comment: can you please share the sample data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/Pandas convert string to time only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801321/python-pandas-convert-string-to-time-only)

Answer (score 6):

Now in 2019, using pandas 0.25.0 and Python 3.7.3.

*(Note : Edited answer to take plotting in account)*

> Even though I specified just hour,minutes,and seconds I am still getting date. Why is that?

According to [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) I think it's because in a pandas Timestamp (equivalent of Datetime) object, the arguments *year, month and day* are **mandatory**, while *hour, minutes and seconds* are optional.
Therefore if you convert your object-type object in a Datetime, it **must have a year-month-day part** - if you don't indicate one, it will be the default `1900-01-01`.

Since you also have a Date column in your sample, you can use it to have a datetime column with the right dates that you can use to plot :

```py
import pandas as pd

df['Time'] = df.Date + " " + df.Time
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

df.plot('Time', subplots=True)
```

With this your 'Time' column will display values like : `2016-07-25 01:12:07` and its dtype is datetime64[ns].

That being said, IF you plot day by day and you only want to compare times within a day (and not dates+times), having a default date does not seem bothering as long as it's the same date for all times - the times will be correctly compared on a same day, be it a wrong one.

And in the least likely case you would still want a time-only column, [this is the reverse operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37802012/11724795) :

```py
import pandas as pd

df['Time-only'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```

As explained before, it doesn't have a date (year-month-day) so it cannot be a datetime object, therefore **this column will be in Object format**.

Comment: Yes, it's totally ok to edit your own answer as soon as you have more/new/correct information to provide. So conclusion is, it's not a duplicate due to plotting involved. I suggest we will delete these comments which are no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract a `time` object like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['12:10:20']], columns={"time": "item"})
time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time[0]
```

After which you can extract desired properties as:

```
hour = time.hour
```

([Source](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.time))

Comment: Gives me more errors
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\a421835\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py in _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name)

Comment: 408             try:
--> 409                 values, tz = tslib.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    410                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)
pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.datetime_to_datetime64 (pandas\tslib.c:29768)()
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9f23978b3fbe> in <module>()
----> 1 time=pd.to_datetime(df.Time,format='%H:%M').time()
C:\Users\a421835\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: I added sample data to allow running example directly

Comment: Okay that worked now. I just needed to replace your [0] with [:] to get it to apply to the entire column. Thanks for that