# Subtracting time within a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to subtract dates and time between columns that I read into python using pandas dataframe. I wrote the code as follows:

```
Time = df['t'] - df['t'].shift(1) + df['t']
```

This leads to error message. My input and intended output are stated below

```
Input data:
t =
9:47:00
9:48:00
9:49:00
9:50:00
9:51:00
9:52:00
9:53:00
9:54:00
```

I am hoping the code will produce the output data(cummulative hour that starts from zero.

```
0
0.016666667
0.033333333
0.05
0.066666667
0.083333333
0.1
```

I also tried to turn it into a string using `datetime.strptime('t',"%H:%M:%S.%f")` and I still get the error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here: please supply a code segment that reproduces the problem, rather than one-line snippets.  Your one-line code references only one column -- two of the terms are the same.

Comment: you seem to get a result of 2t - t[-1], which most likely not what you want in any case. I'd suggest dropping last `df['t']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Chris' solution. You should be working with `timedelta`s from the outset for a simpler solution.

```
v = pd.to_timedelta(df['t'])
((v - v.shift())).dt.total_seconds().cumsum().div(3600).fillna(0)

0    0.000000
1    0.016667
2    0.033333
3    0.050000
4    0.066667
5    0.083333
6    0.100000
7    0.116667
Name: t, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

# assuming you're working with strings:
t = [
    '9:47:00', '9:48:00', '9:49:00', '9:50:00',
    '9:51:00', '9:52:00', '9:53:00', '9:54:00'
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'time' : pd.to_datetime(t, infer_datetime_format=True)})
print(df)
#>                  time
#> 0 2018-08-30 09:47:00
#> 1 2018-08-30 09:48:00
#> 2 2018-08-30 09:49:00
#> 3 2018-08-30 09:50:00
#> 4 2018-08-30 09:51:00
#> 5 2018-08-30 09:52:00
#> 6 2018-08-30 09:53:00
#> 7 2018-08-30 09:54:00

df['time_shift'] = df.shift(-1)
df['tdelt'] = df['time_shift'] - df['time']
x = df.tdelt.astype('timedelta64[s]') / 3600
x = x[1:-1].cumsum()
print(x)
#> 1    0.016667
#> 2    0.033333
#> 3    0.050000
#> 4    0.066667
#> 5    0.083333
#> 6    0.100000
#> Name: tdelt, dtype: float64
```

Created on 2018-08-30 by the [reprexpy package](https://github.com/crew102/reprexpy)

```py
import reprexpy
print(reprexpy.SessionInfo())
#> Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1 (64-bit)
#> Python: 3.6
#> Date: 2018-08-30
#> Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> pandas==0.23.4
#> reprexpy==0.1.1
```

Comment: I believe you can also use [`pd.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) instead of creating a helper series.

Comment: Unable to use your suggested approach. here is the error message:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 368, in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 492, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 744, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 677, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
>>>

Comment: what version of pandas are you using? my solution used 0.23.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801321/python-pandas-convert-string-to-time-only]) is an answer.

Or maybe in other way -

```
# lets have some data to process:
stamps = pd.date_range('2018-05-19 18:15:05', periods=4, freq='2H')
df = pd.DataFrame(stamps)

df.apply(lambda e : e + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))
```

Shows:

> ```
>                 0
> 0 2018-05-19 18:15:06
> 1 2018-05-19 20:15:06
> 2 2018-05-19 22:15:06
> 3 2018-05-20 00:15:06
> ```

And this:

```
df.apply(lambda e : e + datetime.timedelta(seconds=100))
```

> ```
>                     0
> 0 2018-05-19 18:16:45
> 1 2018-05-19 20:16:45
> 2 2018-05-19 22:16:45
> 3 2018-05-20 00:16:45
> ```

Just to see difference. Tip here is to stick with dates. That way `timedelta` works. You can use `combine` to make `Datetime` from `Date`, and `Time`.