# How to just put Hours Minutes and seconds in data frame instead of Year , months and days?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I want to plot a line graph of ECG in **mV** and time in **HH:MM:SS:MMM** . its a 10 second ECG strip.

1. [image of ECG CSV file with two ECG values and time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HAFp.png)

I Have extract the Time column and now i want to convert the time column in dataframe of python and then plot it on graph

but when I apply to_datetime() function it give me the following error

> to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be
>   specified: [day,month,year] is missing

2. [Screenshot of error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u444Z.png)

please Help me to resolve this error , I only want to put **%H:%M:%S.%f** because i don not have the year , months and days.

Comment: You can use any date (except one that's on a daylight saving's day).

Comment: I think This is because pandas doesn't have a data type for time alone as far as I'm aware. The object type in pandas maps to a python base type of string.but i have no solution to this

Answer (score 2):

As commented you can add a date to those times. The date can be arbitrary. Then you can convert to datetime and use them to plot your graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data = {'Time':['11:20:15.333','12:00:00.444', '13:46:00.100'],
       'A':[1,3,2],'B':[5,5,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df["Date"] = "2019-09-09"
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])

df = df[["Datetime", "A", "B"]].set_index("Datetime")

ax = df.plot(x_compat=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S.%f"))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man , just tell me in line : df = df[["Datetime", "A", "B"]].set_index("Datetime") .....................what does .set_index do and how its helpful i have seen it move the title Datatime below other titles but what its functionality ?

Comment: just one thing more , edit your code to show interval  between time on x axis.....like of five second or one minute.

Answer (score 1):

See [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html)

**Date** :

```
df1 = {'Time':['11:20:15.333','10:00:00.444'],'P1':['102','102'],'P2':['240','247']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)
df1
```

**Code** :

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['Time'])
df1
```

**Result**:

```
    Time            P1  P2
0   11:20:15.333000 102 240
1   10:00:00.444000 102 247
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801500/1855988

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `format` you want to convert the time to. You can find out more information [here](http://strftime.org/) about what each symbol means.

```
# before it is object
df['column_name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column_name'], format="%H:%M:%S,%f")
df = df.astype('datetime64')
df['column_name'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['column_name'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').dt.time
# coming back to object
print(df.head())
# print(df.info())
```

Comment: give this error : to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

Comment: I had made some changes in the code. Please see if it works for you now.