# Having Trouble with a DateTime format - need to set first entry then calculate based on time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Now I converted 2 columns that were originally '%H:%M' format toDatetime and it defaulted the Y:M:D to 1900-01-01. How would I be able to name the first row date and then it calculate the date for the rest of the column. I have multiple days in the Actual Time column, so I would need something that adds the next day to the Y:M:D date...

```
>>> dfsched['Actual Time']= pd.to_datetime(dfsched['Actual Time'], format='%H:%M')
>>> dfsched.head()
   Engine   Trip   Arr/ Dept       Schedule Time         Actual Time 
0   670.0  E9207           D 1900-01-01 06:12:00 1900-01-01 05:49:00  
1   670.0  E9207           A 1900-01-01 06:22:00 1900-01-01 06:00:00   
2   670.0   9207           D 1900-01-01 06:39:00 1900-01-01 06:39:00  
3   670.0   9207           A 1900-01-01 06:43:00 1900-01-01 06:44:00    
4   670.0   9207           D 1900-01-01 06:44:00 1900-01-01 06:45:00
```

So to be clear, I'd like to set row one to "2023-11-12" and for later on in Actual Time's DateTime for it to recognize it's now 2012-11-13 and have it set automatically for the next few days.

Comment: can you provide your sample output please?

Comment: for the time formatting part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801321/python-pandas-convert-string-to-time-only

for the date offset: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python/Pandas convert string to time only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801321/python-pandas-convert-string-to-time-only)

Comment: parse to [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) instead of datetime, then add the cumulative sum for each row to a reference date?

Comment: @Yuca I don't think this is an appropriate dupe. OP is *not* looking for a time-only column.

Comment: Yeah the CSV has HH:MM format. In the dataframe, the column is an object. I can get it to be a DateTime but the date (MM DD YY) is wrong. I would like to specify the date of the first row and then have the rest of the rows be the same date but when it rolls over past 23:59 to 0:00, I would like the date to also increment to the next day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I'm assuming that the dataframe `dashed` read from the CSV-file looks something like (I have extended your example to cover the transition to a new day):

```
   Engine   Trip Arr/ Dept Schedule Time Actual Time
0   670.0  E9207         D         06:12       05:49
1   670.0  E9207         A         06:22       06:00
2   670.0   9207         D         06:39       06:39
3   670.0   9207         A         06:43       06:44
4   670.0   9207         D         06:44       06:45
5   670.0   9207         D         22:44       22:45
6   670.0   9207         D         02:15       02:16
```

Now, following the comment from @FObersteiner, you could try

```py
start = pd.Timestamp("2023-11-12")
for col in "Schedule Time", "Actual Time":
    times = pd.to_timedelta(dfshed[col] + ":00")
    days = pd.to_timedelta((times < times.shift()).cumsum(), unit="days")
    dfshed[col] = start + times + days
```

to get

```
   Engine   Trip Arr/ Dept       Schedule Time         Actual Time
0   670.0  E9207         D 2023-11-12 06:12:00 2023-11-12 05:49:00
1   670.0  E9207         A 2023-11-12 06:22:00 2023-11-12 06:00:00
2   670.0   9207         D 2023-11-12 06:39:00 2023-11-12 06:39:00
3   670.0   9207         A 2023-11-12 06:43:00 2023-11-12 06:44:00
4   670.0   9207         D 2023-11-12 06:44:00 2023-11-12 06:45:00
5   670.0   9207         D 2023-11-12 22:44:00 2023-11-12 22:45:00
6   670.0   9207         D 2023-11-13 02:15:00 2023-11-13 02:16:00
```

So first the timestamps get transformed into `timedelta`s `times` with `pd.to_timedelta` (the `+ ":00"` adds the missing seconds). Then identify the transition to a new day by comparing consecutive `times` values: `times < times.shift()`. The `days` are determined by `cumsum`ing over the result (`True` - `1` - identifies a transition, `False` - `0` - otherwise) and then applying `pd.to_timedelta` again (with `unit="days"`). Then calculate the `datetime`s by adding `times + days` to the starting `datetime` (here `2023-11-12`).

But be aware that the identification of the day transition might not be bullet proof (depends on how the actual data look like) - but I don't see another way. Also, it could well be that the whole process has to be done grouped by `Engine`.

Comment: I'll try this today and feedback. Thank you!